# Execute something from the start menu using autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

How do I start something from the windows start menu using autohotkey? I can do

```
Send ^{Esc}MyAppName{Enter}
```

And everything works except the last `{Enter}`. The screen stops on the open start menu after entering `MyAppName`. I can manually hit enter then and it opens. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works, so it was probably an issue of the start menu not opening/responding quite fast enough:

```
Send ^{Esc}
Sleep 2000
Send MyAppName
Sleep 2000
Send {Enter}
```

Answer (score -1):

Adapting the answer of @xdhmoore for `AutoHotkey v2`:

```
#!s::{
    SendEvent "^{Esc}"
    Sleep 1000
    Send "HP Smart"
    Sleep 1000
    SendEvent "{Enter}"
    Sleep 1000
    MouseMove 440,400
} ; win+alt+s  gets mouse ready on  Numériser  button
```